# Puppeteer Failing for more than 11 Urls

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I would like to ask, whats the best way to capture more than 20 screenshots or different Urls?
I have tried the following code.

```
async function sCapture(url, site_name) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720 })
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.screenshot({
    path:`statusImage/${site_name}.jpg`
    });
    await browser.close();
 }
```

Am getting the Urls from my DB like this.

```
db_connection.promise()
.execute("SELECT * FROM `urls`")
.then(([rows]) => {
 
   rows.forEach(user => {
       const url   = user.link;
       const name  = user.link_name;
       console.log(name);
       sCapture(url, name)
       
   });
   db_connection.end();
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Because my DB Table contains more than 50 urls
Before, I was getting this error:

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

After I added the line below. Its just killing my server and I have to do a manual reboot for my site to work again.

```
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;
```

I will appreciate any help rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I think your current code actually starts a new browser instance for each URL you want to fetch and I don't think you need to do that. A separate page is enough. Also, you are currently making all those requests in parallel, which will tax your machine more than doing it in sequence. Putting these two changes together give you something like this:

```js
let browser;

async function sCapture(url, site_name) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720 })
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.screenshot({
    path:`statusImage/${site_name}.jpg`
  });
}

const doit = () => {
  db_connection.promise()
    .execute("SELECT * FROM `urls`")
    .then(([rows]) => {
    
    rows.forEach(async user => {
      const url   = user.link;
      const name  = user.link_name;
      console.log(name);
      await sCapture(url, name);    
    });
    db_connection.end();
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  doit();
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: thanks for you help. 
Am getting this error now.  ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: browser is not defined``` . and its being called the number of times for for each url.

Comment: ah, yes, sorry. The `browser` variable was wrongly scoped. I updated the code. Try now.

Comment: All errors gone. then, there is no actions. The ``` console.log(name);``` worked. but no image captured or anything. So i wrote  ```console.log(site_name)``` inside the ```async function sCapture(url, site_name){}```. It produced nothing. Don't know where I could be wrong.